# For a biological AND Gate to work, do the two inputs need to arrive at the same time?

Tags: synthetic-biology, biological-networks

I understand that AND gates require the two inputs to be present for the output to be produced. However, if one input arrives faster than the other input does the output still get produced?  For example, consider the [split T7 RNAP Expression System](https://www.pnas.org/content/110/13/5028), where one input produces the T7 N-term and the second input produces the T7 C-term and both join to produce the output. So both need to be present to produce the output. If input 1 occurred first than the second input, will the output be 0 or can the N-term wait until the C-term is produced.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: It depends on what physical/biologic/informatic realization of a gate you are talking about. I suggest that you explain more clearly what you are talking about - as is, there is too much hidden information (known only to you) in your question.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are thinking about this like a programmer rather than a hardware or wetware engineer.

- An AND *instruction* in a computer program is evaluated at a particular time, and only the values at that instant matter. Thus, the concept of a value "arriving" can makes sense and one would need to worry about times of arrival.
- An AND *gate* (whether biological, electrical, or other) operates continuously, and is always producing a signal based on what its input levels were in the recent past, with the time delay dependent on its implementation.  Thus, signals do not so much "arrive" as simply change between high and low levels at particular times.

Thus, when one input goes high before the other, the gate is not yet activated, but there is not reason for it not to activate when the other goes high as well, as long as the first signal hasn't dropped to be low again in the mean time.

Now, with a biological system such as this one, it can also get messy because the high and low levels may not be cleanly separated and there may be significant leakage when only one is high.  In the case of the particular system that you are interested in, it looks like there's significant leakage for many of the configurations, so in many cases the second signal need not even arrive for the system to be at least partially on.